# Python/Django: Which authorize.net library should I use?

Tags: python, django, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I need authorize.net integration for subscription payments, likely using CIM. The requirements are simple - recurring monthly payments, with a few different price points. Customer credit card info will be stored a authorize.net .

There are quite a few libraries and code snippets around, I'm looking for recommendations as to which work best.

- Satchmo seems more than I need, and it looks like it's complex.
- [Django-Bursar](http://bitbucket.org/bkroeze/django-bursar/overview/) seems like what I need, but it's listed as alpha.
- The [adroll/authorize library](http://bitbucket.org/adroll/authorize/wiki/Home) also looks pretty good.
- The CIM XML APIs don't look too bad, I could connect directly with them.

And there are quite a few other code snippets.

What's the best choice right now, given my fairly simple requirements?

Comment: What did you end up settling on if you don't mind my asking? Working on a project with very similar requirements.

Comment: Nothing yet, but will likely be trying the CIM XML APIs. Will update the question as I learn more, and I'd appreciate if you do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth we ended up using the [adroll authorize library](http://bitbucket.org/adroll/authorize/wiki/Home). Both Paython and django-authorizenet look interesting, will be checking those out.

Answer (score 16):

Long story short, none of the existing solutions met my needs. They were either unmaintained, uncommented, untested, or lacked saved cards. So of course I built my own solution and open-sourced it:

AuthorizeSauce: https://github.com/jeffschenck/authorizesauce

It handles basic transactions (the AIM API), saved cards (the CIM API), and recurring payments (the ARB API). It is fully documented and has a full test suite.

I expect the original poster has long since moved on, but if it can help anyone else avoid some of the pain of payment processing, I'd be overjoyed.

Comment: Thanks, it's nice to have something available that isn't 4 years old, unmaintained, or a giant question mark.

Comment: @Jeff Schenck is there support of Server Integration Method?

Comment: I love this library; it's easily the simplest, most pythonic implementation I've seen.

Comment: Looks nice. However, it does not support the Direct Post Method, does it? As far as I know, this is much better than dealing with compliance issues.

Answer (score 9):

Edit: https://github.com/agiliq/merchant/blob/master/billing/gateways/authorize_net_gateway.py
looks pretty nice, haven't tried it yet.

Edit: [For the next project I have that uses authorize.net, I'm going to take a close look at: http://github.com/zen4ever/django-authorizenet It looks pretty nice.  I don't think that it has support for recurring payments though.]

In the past I have made little one-off implementations.

For simple post to the AIM payment gateway, you can use something like this:

```
URL = 'https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll'
API = {'x_login':'XXX',
'x_tran_key':'XXX', 'x_method':'CC', 'x_type':'AUTH_ONLY',
'x_delim_data':'TRUE', 'x_duplicate_window':'10', 'x_delim_char':'|',
'x_relay_response':'FALSE', 'x_version':'3.1'}

def call_auth(amount, card_num, exp_date, card_code, zip_code, request_ip=None):
    '''Call authorize.net and get a result dict back'''
    import urllib2, urllib
    payment_post = API
    payment_post['x_amount'] = amount
    payment_post['x_card_num'] = card_num
    payment_post['x_exp_date'] = exp_date
    payment_post['x_card_code'] = card_code
    payment_post['x_zip'] = zip_code
    payment_request = urllib2.Request(URL, urllib.urlencode(payment_post))
    r = urllib2.urlopen(payment_request).read()
    return r

def call_capture(trans_id): # r.split('|')[6] we get back from the first call, trans_id
    capture_post = API
    capture_post['x_type'] = 'PRIOR_AUTH_CAPTURE'
    capture_post['x_trans_id'] = trans_id
    capture_request = urllib2.Request(URL, urllib.urlencode(capture_post))
    r = urllib2.urlopen(capture_request).read()
    return r
```

To authorize, you do something like:

```
            r = authorize.call_auth(
                unicode(decimal_total),
                request.POST.get('card_num'),
                request.POST.get('exp_date'),
                request.POST.get('card_code'),
                request.POST.get('zip_code') if request.POST.get('zip_code') else address.zip_code,
            )
            if r.split('|')[0] == '1':
              # it's good, we have authorized the card...
            else:
              error = "%s Please try again." % (r.split('|')[3])
```

then, we can capture:

```
        r = authorize.call_capture(trans_id) # r.split('|')[6] in first response..
        if r.split('|')[0] == '1':
            # we captured it.
        else:
            error = r.split('|')[3]
```

There are more options, ways to request, nuances in the response to parse... I assume b/c `A` in `AIM` stands for `advanced` that all of the authorize.net options are available.

http://developer.authorize.net/guides/AIM/

I know that your question is what lib is best .. well, it might be easiest just to implement your own little bit of ad-hoc request and response for your specific requirements rather than trying to trove through an api on top of an api.

Comment: Oh, if any finds flaw, has suggestion, comment, I would love to hear.  Maybe we can build a nice flexible and featureful but still lightweight way to do more.

Comment: Agreed. A light-weight implementation would be great. I just found zc authorizedotnet in PyPi. Have you any experience with this?

Comment: I actually have an upcoming project for which I'm going to have a go with:

http://github.com/zen4ever/django-authorizenet

Answer (score 6):

There is always Paython: https://github.com/abunsen/Paython

Currently supports 5+ payment gateways:

1. Authorize.net
2. First Data/Linkpoint
3. Innovative Gateway (from intuit)
4. PlugnPay
5. Stripe

Here is an example:

```
from paython import CreditCard, AuthorizeNet
```

set up a card first:

```
credit_card = CreditCard(
      number = '4111111111111111',
      exp_mo = '02',
      exp_yr = '2012',
      first_name = 'John',
      last_name = 'Doe',
      cvv = '911',
      strict = False
  )
```

check if its valid:

```
if not credit_card.is_valid(): return 'houston, we have a problem' # checks card number + expiration date
```

Set up customer data to charge, not all fields are required:

```
customer_data = dict(
      address='123 Main St', 
      address2='Apt 1', 
      city='Pleasantville', 
      state='IA', 
      zipcode='54321', 
      country='US', 
      phone='654-369-9589', 
      email='john@localwoodshop.com', 
      ip='127.0.0.1')
```

authorize against gateway, options include debug output or test credentials:

```
  api = AuthorizeNet(username='test', password='testpassword', debug=True, test=True)
  gateway_response = api.auth(amount='0.05', credit_card=credit_card, billing_info=customer_data, shipping_info=None)
```

now you can settle:

```
  api = AuthorizeNet(username='test', password='testpassword', debug=True, test=True)
  gateway_response = api.settle(amount='0.05', trans_id='2156729380')
```

Answer (score 3):

I recently wrote this API for Python and Authorize.net after failing to find one that supported all of Authorize.net's functionality.

https://github.com/vcatalano/py-authorize

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a bit late, but hopefully it helps others.

I recently came across `Py-Authorize` which has some great documentation, compared to the other packages available. You can install it via:

```
pip install Py-Authorize
```

It seems to install a dependency (`colondar`) which when installed via `pip` is outdated so you can get the latest (at the time of this writing) by doing the following:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/Pylons/colander.git@1.0b1
```

The docs are here: http://vcatalano.github.io/py-authorize/index.html

Works great in my experience, however for the project I am using it on I only needed AuthCapture and not ARB or anything...give it a try.  Best package I've found so far.