# What is the Simplest Possible Payment Gateway to Implement? (using Django)

Tags: python, django, payment-gateway, payment-processing

I'm developing a web application that will require users to either make one time deposits of money into their account, or allow users to sign up for recurring billing each month for a certain amount of money.

I've been looking at various payment gateways, but most (if not all) of them seem complex and difficult to get working. I also see no real `active` Django projects which offer simple views for making payments.

Ideally, I'd like to use something like Amazon FPS, so that I can see online transaction logs, refund money, etc., but I'm open to other things.

I just want the EASIEST possible payment gateway to integrate with my site. I'm not looking for anything fancy, whatever does the job, and requires < 10 hours to get working from start to finish would be perfect.

I'll give answer points to whoever can point out a good one. Thanks!

**EDIT**: This is to accept payments in the US only. I don't need an international payment gateway. And it only needs to support US English.

Comment: You should also mention which country it's for, because not all payment gateways work in all countries.

Comment: Thanks. I've added it. I'm looking for a US payment gateway.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Braintree](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/) has a Python client library that could give you the quick integration that you're looking for. Here is the link to the Braintree developer documentation for the Python SDK: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/transactions/python.

Comment: I'm giving you the answer points. Why? Because after looking at every other payment gateway for 1 hour or more (reading their websites, documentation, etc.) I was able to spend approximately 5 minutes on your site, and feel completely 100% comfortable using your services.

1. Your pastie code looks exactly like what I've been searching for.
2. Your website is clear, and understandable.
3. The customer testimonials from github and 37signals told me that if I didn't use this, I suck.

Thanks. I'm looking forward to using you guys!

Hopefully this thread is of use to someone else too!

Answer (score 2):

Authorize.net is pretty simple, this question suggested a few Django apps that are at least started: [Python/Django: Which authorize.net library should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637902/python-django-which-authorize-net-library-should-i-use)

Comment: I've looked at these, but none of them really live up to what I'm looking for--a SIMPLE payment processing gateway with a SIMPLE API.

Also (hopefully), something that is tested and not BETA.

Comment: +1 Agreed. Authorize.Net has the easiest API to use of all of the payment gateways and third party processors out there.

Answer (score 2):

I've done successful integrations for both Google Checkout and PayPal ExpressCheckout in Django. Both services have stable, well-developed APIs, and neither one was too difficult to implement. There are good Python libraries already written to do the heavy lifting for you, too.

Answer (score 0):

You may check [Django payments app Mamona](http://github.com/emesik/mamona) which I started not so long time ago. It currently handles PayPal only. It doesn't support refunds and recurring payments yet, but is **very simple** and can be attached to any other application without changing it's code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider enabling more than one payment gateways. If you add only one, and this gateway fails for some reason you'll start losing money (actually happened to one of the persons I know).